# Is it possible to add UIView (Admob) in uitableviewcontroller or in uicollectionviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, admob

I want to add admob in uitableviewcontroller or in uicollectionviewcontroller at the bottom of screen. So for that I have to add uiView (GAD BannerView) at the bottom of uitableview controller or uicolleectionview controller. So how can I do this? 
Actually we can add uiview easily in uiviewcontroller but how can I add this in uitableviewcontroller or uicollectionviewcontroller?

Comment: check this link     http://www.appcoda.com/ios-iad-introduction/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can also add Ad Mob in `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`.`UITableViewController` have a one property toolbar. You can add AdMob to `Toolbar` as below.

```
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
    self.banner = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
    self.banner.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX";
    self.banner.rootViewController = self;
    [self.navigationController.toolbar addSubview:self.banner];

    GADRequest *request;
    [self.banner loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its possible. you can add banner ad in header or footer view of tableview or collectionview. Like this in table view

```
UIView * bannerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 50)];

[bannerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

_tableView.tableFooterView = bannerView;
```